# ExtJS 4.1 - Nested hasOne associated in JSON

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "arbitraryAttribute": "arbitraryValue",
    "thing": {
        "thingKey1": "thingValue1",
        "thinkKey2": "thingValue2"
    }
}
```

This model is represented like so:

```
Ext.define("MyModel", {
    extends: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "id", type: "string"},
        {name: "arbitraryAttribute", type: "string"},
    ],
    hasOne: [
        {
            model: "Thing",
            name: "thing"
        }
    ]
});

Ext.define("Thing", {
    extends: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "thingKey1", type: "string"},
        {name: "thingKey2", type: "string"}
    ]
});
```

The proxy is a simple json proxy. The JSON it is getting looks like that which I presented, but my record seems to have no knowledge of the Thing model. Is there any additional plumbing I need to set up to get MyModel to pull the nested Thing json?

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot to set the thing_id in MyModel. Also this doesnt work at all in ExtJs.
You can now set the thing_id via JSON but not the whole object as you do (and it should).

It will autoLoad the complete object via the models proxy if required.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'status'],
    associations: [
        { type: 'hasOne', model: 'Status', associationKey: 'status'  }
    ]
});

Ext.define('Status', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'title'],
});
```

[Demo here](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-1-read-complex-json-with-hasone-association)